# How to add RGBA color map to single band GeoTIFF using GeoTools 2.x?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am developing a light weight GIS application, and am looking for the simplest way to add an RGBA color map to a single band GeoTIFF using GeoTools 2.x?

Comment: To use RGBA in single band raster you have to use indexed color mode.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
I would check this page http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Raster+Symbolizer+support

Simone.

Comment: Broken link: http://old.geotools.org/Raster-Symbolizer-support_73302189.html